# Delphi 5: Error asigning click event to TImage

Tags: delphi, events, click, timage

I created an custom control for the TStatusbar.
Its in old Delphi5 for windows.
The goal is, if I click the panel or the image, an event should be raise.
But I get an error by assigning the click event to the image.
The error is in line starts with
_Image.OnClick := ButtonClick;
Can anyone solve this? Thank you!

I modified the code, it works now.
Any suggestions to make it even better?
My main mistake was that I misunderstand

```
self := TPanelImageButton(template);
```

I read, that in this case self should inherit all from template.
But I guess this was wrong. So I now set the properties I need in code.

Thank you!

```
unit PanelImageButton;

{
Usage:
var
PanelUser: TPanelImageButton;

PanelUser :=TPanelImageButton.Create(self,PanelUserTemplate,Image1);
PanelUser.OnClick:= PanelUserClicked;

procedure TForm1.PanelUserClicked(Sender:TObject);
begin

end;

FormClose() -> FreeAndNil(PanelUser);
}

interface
//Delphi:   uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;
//Lazarus: uses Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;
uses
  Windows, Messages, Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls,
  Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls,{für Fehler}debug;

type
  //define usercontrol
  TPanelImageButton = class(TPanel)
  private
    _PanelIndex: integer;
    _Image: TImage;
    //define event
    FOnClick: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Resizeing(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure Click; override; //override;//dynamic;
  public
    constructor Create(TheOwner: TComponent); overload; override;
    constructor Create(TheOwner: TComponent; template: TPanel; imageTemplate: TImage);
      reintroduce; overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function HasImage(): boolean;
  published
    property PanelIndex: integer read _PanelIndex write _PanelIndex;
    property OnClick: TNotifyEvent read FOnClick write FOnClick;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('PHOENIX', [TPanelImageButton]);
end;

constructor TPanelImageButton.Create(TheOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(TheOwner);
  PanelIndex := -1;
  _Image := nil;
  self.Caption := '';
end;

constructor TPanelImageButton.Create(TheOwner: TComponent;
  template: TPanel; imageTemplate: TImage);
begin
  inherited Create(TheOwner);
  try
    PanelIndex := -1;
    self.Caption := template.Caption;
    self.Color := template.Color;
    self.Font := template.Font;

    if (assigned(imageTemplate)) then
    begin
      _Image := TImage.Create(self);
      _Image.Picture.Assign(imageTemplate.Picture);
      _Image.Transparent := True;
      _Image.Parent := self;
      _Image.Visible := True;
      _Image.AutoSize := False;
      _Image.Stretch := True;
      _Image.OnClick := ButtonClick;
      imageTemplate.Visible := False;
      _Image.Cursor := crHandPoint;
    end
    else
    if assigned(_Image) then
      FreeAndNil(_Image);
    self.OnResize := Resizeing;
    //keine Ränder:
    self.BevelOuter := bvNone;
    self.BevelInner := bvNone;
    self.Cursor := crHandPoint;
  except
    on e: Exception do
      WriteDebug('PanelImageButton: ' + e.Message);
  end;
end;

destructor TPanelImageButton.Destroy;
begin
  try
    self.Parent := nil;
    if assigned(_Image) then
    begin
      _Image.parent := nil;
      FreeAndNil(_Image);
    end;
  except
    on e: Exception do
      WriteDebug('TPanelImageButton.Destroy: ' + e.Message);
  end;
  inherited;
end;

function TPanelImageButton.HasImage(): boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if assigned(_Image) then
    Result := True;
end;

procedure TPanelImageButton.Resizeing(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not (assigned(_Image)) then
    exit;
  try
    _Image.Left := 6;
    _Image.Height := self.Height - 12;
    _Image.Top := 6;
    _Image.Width := _Image.Height;
  except
    on e: Exception do
      WriteDebug('PanelImageButton: ' + e.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TPanelImageButton.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Click;
end;

procedure TPanelImageButton.Click;
begin
  try
    if Assigned(FOnClick) then
      FOnClick(Self);
  except
    on e: Exception do
      WriteDebug('PanelImageButton: ' + e.Message);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: `self := TPanelImageButton(template)` doesn't look like it would lead anywhere useful

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code is riddled with bugs. Just to mention one of them: `FreeAndNil(FOnClick);`

Comment: When did you write this code? I can't believe it can ever have worked. Is it new?

Comment: What is the error you get? Why are you casting to `TImage` in `_Image := TImage(imageTemplate);`? Are you perhaps passing something that is not a `TImage`?

Comment: I have a panel and a image on the main form. This I like to pass to the TPanelImageButton:
 buttonUser := TPanelImageButton.Create(StatusBar, PanelUserTemplate, ImageUser);
  buttonUser.OnClick := @buttonUserClick;

Answer (score 1):

I propose that you read up on:

- **`Self`** - and what it is for and that assigning something else to it basically makes it useless. You could have made it `_Image.Parent := template;`. But you assigned `template` to `self` and then later you do `self.OnResize := Resizeing;`. Do you want to handle `OnResize` for this `TPanelImageButton` (which should have been `Self` if you did not change it) or do you want to handle `OnResize` for `template`? Leave `self` alone. Use it to access this instance of the class you are currently coding in.
- **Events** - You are trying to free an event variable. Why? It only points to a method. It was not created. Go see how the components that are included with Delphi do events.
- **`@` operator** - In one of you comments above you do `buttonUser.OnClick := @buttonUserClick;`. What is that about? The `@` operator is discussed everywhere. Read up. Its a cool thing but should be used correctly. This blog post is so cool: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html

There are some basics that needs to be addressed and I strongly recommend you study how components in Delphi are made.

The last very important thing is for you to include the errors you see into the Stack Overflow question. If you did that we could have given you more specific answers on your particular issue. You would have returned complaining about some other error but at least you would have learned about the first one, hopefully.

Comment: Hello. 
What I want: A user control which is placed in the statusbar.
The user control should use a image and a panel from the mainForm as a template.
The reason is, if something is changed, like border or color at design time, it also is done in runtime, because the usercontrol inherits the both controls from the mainform, tpanel & timage.
So what I read is that in the constructor of TPanelImageButton

self := TPanelImageButton(template);

should create an Instance of my TPanelImageButton and take the properties from the template.
Is this correct?

Comment: The same should happen with imageTemplate, _Image which should take all from imageTemplate.
and bot components, the TPanelImageButton and _Image  should fire an event OnClick.

Where I'm totally lost is where to declare stuff. I read a lot of different hints.
so should the _Image be protected?

Thanks for any help & with best regards, Thomas.

Comment: Random flailing isn't going to work. You need to find a good introductory text, and read it, working through the examples carefully. Solid understanding of the language is necessary before attempting to write components, which is an advanced level task.